# My Javascript function is not getting called on button click

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

```
function createHTTPObj_newvehicle() {
    var http = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

   return http;
}

function newvehicle() {
    var http = createHTTPObj_newvehicle();
    debugger;
    http.open('POST', 'NavigateServlet?action=NewVehicle', true);
    http.send(null);
} 

function createHTTPObj_newbudget() {
    var http = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    return http;
}

function newbudget() {    
    var http = createHTTPObj_newbudget();
    debugger;
    http.open('POST', 'NavigateServlet?action=NewBudget', true);
    http.send(null);
}
```

---

javascript page

### I am having 2 button on click of which this java script should get called. but I am unable to call it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NavigateServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.avigma.controller.NavigateServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NavigateServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NavigateServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

web.xml

Comment: add your html file also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AJAX POST requests you have to do the following after `open()` and before `send()`:

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: Yes, now it is getting called but giving 2 errors                                                        1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)                                                                                                             2. 404 (Not Found)                                                                                                  on   http.send(null);

Comment: Yes you should send data in your POST call in the send() method, and not null. You can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started for more informations.